# Laravel, search input error GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/meusprocessos/processos/search/Anula 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, search, routes

I am doing a project on laravel, and I have a search input where I use jquery to search for the word.

But I getting the following error, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/meusprocessos/processos/Search?search=word 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here resumed html:

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Dashboard')

@section('content')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <div class="col-md-9 mb-5">
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <div class="has-feedback">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control input-sm" id="search" value="" placeholder="Procurar Processo pelo nome">
                       <!-- <a type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="processosSearch">Procurar</a> -->
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='processos'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.2.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-2krYZKh//PcchRtd+H+VyyQoZ/e3EcrkxhM8ycwASPA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

        $("#refreshProcessos").on('click', function () {
            $("#processos").html("<img src=' https://flevix.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Curve-Loading.gif' >")
            $("#processos").load("{!! route('meusprocessos.processos') !!}")
        });

          $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $("#processos").load("{!! route('meusprocessos.processosSearch') !!}" + "?search=" + val )
    });

        $(document).on('click', 'a.readProcesso', function (e) {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id")
            //console.log(id);
            $("#processos").html("<img src=' https://flevix.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Curve-Loading.gif' >")
            $("#processos").load("{!! route('meusprocessos.processo') !!}" + "/" + id)
        });

        $("#processos").html("<img src=' https://flevix.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Curve-Loading.gif' >")
        $("#processos").load("{!! route('meusprocessos.processos') !!}")

    </script>
@stop
```

Here the route:

```
Route::get('/meusprocessos/processos/Search', [App\Http\Controllers\MeusProcessosController::class, 'processosSearch'])->name('meusprocessos.processosSearch');
```

Here de controller:

```
  public function processosSearch(Resquest $request)
    {
        $search = $request->val;
       // $search = "Anulado";
        $processos = Processo::where('nome', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->where('funcionario_id', \auth()->user()->id)
            ->get();
        $departamentos = Departamento::all();

        return view('meusprocessos.processosSearch')->with(['processos' => $processos,
            'departamentos' => $departamentos
        ]);
    }
```

Its not going to the view at all, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Its problably the way I am applying the routes, but I don't know how doing it in a diferent way.

I don't think is needed the rest of the code, but its here:

https://github.com/Maneneco/EmailManager

Comment: have you committed and pushed the local repo to git repo? I see no routes or controllers.

Comment: your declared route doesnt accept a 4th sub term, change it to `Route::get('meusprocessos/processos/search/{val}'`

Comment: @itachi check profile branch please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

route:

```
Route::get('/meusprocessos/processos/Search/{search?}', [App\Http\Controllers\MeusProcessosController::class, 'processosSearch'])->name('meusprocessos.processosSearch');
```

jquery:

```
   $("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
            var val = $.trim(this.value);
            if (e.key === 'Backspace') { //Use this to include backspace on keyup
                $("#processos").load("{!! route('meusprocessos.processosSearch') !!}/" + val )
            }
            $("#processos").load("{!! route('meusprocessos.processosSearch') !!}/" + val )
        });
```

controller:

```
  public function processosSearch($search = null)
    {
        $departamentos = Departamento::all();

        if($search == null){ //in case there is nothing on the input
            $processos = Processo::all();
        }else{
            $processos = Processo::where('nome', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->where('funcionario_id', \auth()->user()->id)
                ->get();
        }

        return view('meusprocessos.processosSearch')->with(['processos' => $processos,
            'departamentos' => $departamentos
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code you need to add the $val variable to the Route:

```
Route::get('meusprocessos/processos/search/{val}', [App\Http\Controllers\MeusProcessosController::class, 'processosSearch'])->name('meusprocessos.processosSearch');
```

With that being said I'd also like to recommend you to use post requests when you want to have a route for search, and instead of passing the search query in the url, you should pass it in the request body.

Something like this:

routes/web.php

```
Route::post('meusprocessos/processos/search', [App\Http\Controllers\MeusProcessosController::class, 'processosSearch'])->name('meusprocessos.processosSearch');
```

In your jQuery search:

```
$("#processos").post("{!! route('meusprocessos.processosSearch') !!}", { search: val });
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function processosSearch(Request $request)
{
    $val = $request->search;
    echo $val;
    $search = $val;
    $processos = Processo::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->where('funcionario_id', \auth()->user()->id)
        ->get();
    $departamentos = Departamento::all();

    return view('meusprocessos.processosSearch')->with([
        'processos' => $processos,
        'departamentos' => $departamentos
    ]);
}
```

Of course don't forget to use the Request in your controller, at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

If for any reason you cannot use a post request, you can still do it using a get request like so:

Route:

```
Route::get('meusprocessos/processos/search', [App\Http\Controllers\MeusProcessosController::class, 'processosSearch'])->name('meusprocessos.processosSearch');
```

Controller:

```
public function processosSearch(Request $request)
{
    $val = $request->search;
    echo $val;
    $search = $val;
    $processos = Processo::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->where('funcionario_id', \auth()->user()->id)
        ->get();
    $departamentos = Departamento::all();

    return view('meusprocessos.processosSearch')->with([
        'processos' => $processos,
        'departamentos' => $departamentos
    ]);
}
```

You can then use it in jquery like so:

```
$("#processos").load("{!! route('meusprocessos.processosSearch') !!}"+ "?search=" + val)
```

Comment: I have to use load, or the page will not work. on jquery

Comment: with val route : Missing required parameter for [Route: meusprocessos.processosSearch] [URI: meusprocessos/processos/search/{val}] [Missing parameter: val].

Comment: I have modified the post so that you can still use load.

Comment: I am testing, meanwhile just saying that the post is doubled, I don´t know if that was the intention or not.

Comment: Even with the Load, I use the post route?

Comment: If you want to use the .load, then you should use the get route in your routes/web.php not post.

Look at the bottom of the modified answer.

Comment: And the controller is the same? Request is not applied only to post objects?

Comment: Yea the same as i described it, the Request applies to both get data and post data.

Comment: jquery.min.js:2          GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/meusprocessos/processos/Search?search=word 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I might be missing something, but even applying that does not work, its a diferent error tho, not 404 anymore

Comment: what kind of error are you getting

Comment: Since I am using load, laravel does nor respond to it. But I am getting jquery.min.js:2 GET 127.0.0.1:8000/meusprocessos/processos/Search?search=word 500 (Internal Server Error) on console

Comment: I'd recommend you to debug that by trying the request in your browser first and see what exact error you are getting.